# OpenLDAP Setup help: SASL/GSSAPI authentication started

Tags: openldap, kerberos, sasl

I am trying to setup & configure OpenLDAP on Fedora Core 13. I've gotten as far as compiling and installing **OpenLDAP v2.4.23**.

Whenever I try to run one of the LDAP commands (like `ldapsearch`), I get the following error message:

```
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found)
```

I looked up on this on Google and one solution seems to be configuring Kerberos to work properly first using **kinit**.

However, I do not want Kerberos on my system. Is it possible to make OpenLDAP not use Kerberos at all? Do I need to compile with a suitable option? Or is it that **I MUST use** Kerberos with OpenLDAP?

Comment: FWIW, `GSSAPI` is only _one_ SASL mechanism. There are several others, including `PLAIN`.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to authenticate with Kerberos, you need to tell the OpenLDAP tools that by using the `-x` command line option.  From the man page for `ldapsearch`:

```
       -x     Use simple authentication instead of SASL.
```

When using `-x`, you will also need `-D`, to specify your bind DN, and you will need to provide the password via either `-W` (to prompt for the password) or `-y file` to read the password from *file*.

Comment: Are there any appropriate syntax for ldap.conf, to make it default for every program?

Comment: Looking at the [docs for ldap.conf](https://openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.5-Release&arch=default&format=html), I don't see anything that seems likely. I think "how to bind" is generally left up to the individual application.

Comment: oook, moving from my old setup to new becoming quite interesting. I'd say it's becoming TOO interesting